# Data can't be sent on form submit?

Tags: php, forms

This is my code:

```
<?php
require_once "connect.php";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    if(!empty($email))
    {
        $insert = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO creations(email) VALUES (?)");
        $insert->bind_param('s', $email);
    }
}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="">

            <input type="text" name="email">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I submit anything in the email input box, I get an error saying this:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in /home/xx/xx/xx/xx on line 12.

I've tried this with a few different forms and got the same error. I've double checked everything on both my database and in my PHP code...

Comment: The prepared statement is failing (and returning `false`). The syntax looks ok. Is there a mistake in the table or column name?

Comment: @Anonymous I am successfully connecting to the database. For the column and table name. My table name is called creations and I have only 2 columns. And id that is set to auto increment and an "email" column

Comment: Then enable errors and see what it says. There should be some sort of warning on this line: `$insert = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO creations(email) VALUES (?)");`

Comment: you're using prepared statements; drop the custom function and you'll see magic happen.

Comment: Do I turn it on by saying error_reporting(1)? I delete the bind_param statement, and the error went away, when I added the bind_param statement the error came back

Comment: @Fred-ii- Which custom function? The test_input function?

Comment: that's a big 10-4 ;-) and use `!empty()` for the POST array. btw, it's a scope issue

Comment: I removed the function altogether, but I am still getting the same error. Where do I use !empty() exactly?

Comment: now it all boils down to which MySQL api you're using to connect with. if it isn't mysqli then there's the problem.

Comment: oh and you're not executing the query.

Comment: I'm really suspecting you did some query with prepared statement in `connect.php` but didn't close it and reusing the connection.

Comment: @Fred-ii- In the connect.php I did use mysqli and I did close the connection. The execute part is in my complex form and I am still getting the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick let me know if you have any problems.

//CODE

```
<?php
//PATH --- /var/www/html/connect.php
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/connect.php");
if (isset($_POST["email"])){
    $email = filter_data($_POST["email"]);
    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO creations(email) VALUES (?)"); 
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close(); 
}
function filter_data($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="">
            <input type="text" name="email">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: so this "should work" part; enlighten everyone with what you added ;-)

Comment: Haha yeah same logic just better naming conventions :P, I just finished testing it though it works fine.

Comment: With this, I am getting: Fatal error: Method name must be a string in .... on line 5

Comment: @Razer it must be your db connection... for testing and clarity just create the new db conn object in the same statement I'll update the code above to show it just for clarity... try it with your credentials for your database obviously.

Comment: @Razer I also caught that I originally posted "INSERT INTO users(email)" which I was using for testing, not creations(email) like you have for your db, I just update the code above though with creations(email).

Comment: When I replaced my code with your code, it worked!! 
This was my connection.php code:
<?php
 $db= new mysqli("localhost", "xx", "xx", "xx");
 
 if($db->connect_errno)
 {
  die("Hmm, it looks like we're experiencing some problems. Nothing to do on your part; we've got it covered!");
 }
 else
 {
  
  $db->close();
 }
?>

Comment: @Razer Okay perfect yea must of been the user(email) I originally posted.

Comment: I don't understand what was wrong with my connect.php code though?

Comment: @Razer I don't think there was anything wrong with it try and put it back, I think what happened was you copied the code I originally posted which had "INSERT INTO users(email)" not what your db has "INSERT INTO creations(email)". Put it back in and let me know if works still if not its simply a path error, and I'll show you how to fix it.

Comment: This is what I put back in require_once "submit/connect.php"; If I put only connect.php, it would give me the same error. But when I put submit/
It doesn't give me anything, it just redirects to a blank page, and my database doesn't update. Submit is the folder connect.php is in, but it's also the same folder my form file is in

Comment: @Razer okay yea I figure it out what your problem is, in the external "connect.php" file your killing the db connection... you checking if(db->error) true kill script.... or else(db->close()) killing the script... just remove the else statement at the end.

Comment: @JordanDavis You are awesome. I have one last question. If I wanted to put my connect.php file outside of the web directory, and into the home/** directory? How do I accomplish this?

Comment: @Razer yea no problem... so the best way to that would be to use the $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] global variable if you using apache "/var/www/html" should be your root directory, then you can just append whatever path as a string to it... example would be:  require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/core/submit/connect.php");  which would print out --"/var/www/html/core/submit/connect.php" or for you example :  require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/connect.php");

Comment: @Razer I'll update the code above to show it to you...

Comment: @JordanDavis Hmm, for some reason when I click submit, I see a blank page and the database doesn't update

Comment: @Razer if you don't specify the $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] by default the path starts from the current directory the executing file is in. If your had a file in say "/core/db/user.php" and you wanted to require/include another file the path would start from the "/core/db/" -directory. Say the require/include file you want is "/core/connect.php" then you could  put --- require("../../connect.php") the "../" will take you back a directory, there are some built in functions in php which get the parent directory like dirname() as well as the absolute path to the file realpath().

Comment: @Razer you moved the "connect.php"-file to this path "/var/www/html/connect.php" right?

Comment: I moved the connect.php file outside of the web directory. I am using godaddy. The public_html directory is the web directory, and I moved it directly outside of that folder.

Comment: @Razer Okay yea it needs to be in the public directory (web directory) if it's not in the web-directory then you'll get a permission error. Place it in inside the web directory which is "/var/www/html" so it should be in the /var/www/html/connect.php"

Comment: @JordanDavis The reason why I'm not placing it in the public directory is because I heard that it'll be more easily accessible to attackers since it is out to the public, so they can just view the source code and find out the password and username to my data base

Comment: @Razer no it's fine there, PHP is server-side so it won't send it to the client. There are other ways to do it though like writing a compiled cgi-program in a languages like C#, C++, Pearl and editing your apache config file (htttpd.conf) -or- editing your php config file (php.ini) but these all are a much more complex implementations.

Comment: Oh so let's say I added connect.php in the same folder as the form, and if the user typed in the address, and viewed source code...he wouldn't find anything?

Comment: @Razer exactly go and place whatever domain or ip you have followed by the "/connect.php" so (http://example.com/connect.php) or (http://random-ip/connect.php) nothing will be generated... even if they don't use the browser and use a GET request via cmd-line it won't print anything...

Comment: @JordanDavis And just to make sure, my form is secure from injection?

Comment: @Razer yeah your good, prepared statements protect against SQL Injections so you don't need to run mysqli->real_string() before hand any the cleaned up the whitespaces, tags, etc with the filter_data() function.

Comment: @Razer here is the link the PHP Manual page -->http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php it states in the 2nd bullet that the driver (mysqli) takes care of it for you.

Comment: @JordanDavis Thanks so much!

Comment: @Razer yea no problem man, let me know if you need help with anything else.